# Run a console application as a build task that outputs results of a test

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to find a way to run a console app written in .net, that outputs a return value as **true** or **false**, based on this value, I would like to cancel or progress with the build stage.

My console app runs a simple test to see if certain data exist on a users profile.

Does anyone know how I might go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a value of `true` or `false` is not how applications typically report success or failure. The idiom is to exit with a return code of 0 for success, and non-zero for failure.

You can continue to have it print `true`/`false`, but have it return an appropriate exit code.

You can then run the application using a `Command Line` task in your build, and check the "Fail on Standard Error" flag

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to solve this. I have managed to "fail" the task on standard error using try/catch block. I am wondering, based on your explanation - is there a better or more efficient way to throw an error?

Comment: @Daniel - off topic - but is it possible to return characters (not error codes) from the command line task and use in the pipeline? For example - using environment variables is one option?

Answer (score -1):

AzureDevOps does have support for test results from different test frameworks.

Maybe you could return a supported .xml from your console app instead.

I wouldn't suggest rolling your own test app but use the existing build task Visual Studio Test instead:

[image: Visual Studio Test Task]

However if you do roll your own you should return .xml in one of these formats (JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, XUnit) and then use the build task to publish them to AzureDevOps to see the results there.

[image: Publish Test Results]

Comment: This does not answer the question. There is no "test framework" involved, per the original poster's question.

Comment: @DanielMann given the current question title ("outputs results of a test") and the tags (azure-devops and pipelines), i have provided a solution that i think people will find useful when testing. I realize (reading the question again) that OP might not be testing code here. You answer better provides a concrete solution, but i still think my answer can provide value here.